# Performance counters for Worker Role in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, performancecounter, azure-worker-roles

I am using the Performance counters called "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" to fetch the CPU utilization percentage from the storage account associated.But I check with the Azure Portal metrics chart data, the data varies with enormous amount of difference. I am getting value like "0.33%" in storage account but in the azure portal I see data like "1.87%" in the cpu percentage area.

why this much of difference exist in the portal?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Portal is tracking CPU differently and from "outside" of the VM, while your WADPerformanceCounters is tracking data from the inside of the VM.  The difference between 0.33 and 1.87 for a volatile metric such as CPU is not that huge and can be attributed to different timing of capturing the CPU as well as the fact that there is probably a difference in how CPU Usage of a VM is tracked by the Azure platform and how "Windows OS" inside the VM is tracking it.

Comment: I also consider this link conclusion _https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2016/05/12/understanding-cpu-metric-data-from-azure-cloud-services/_